# Regarding Static and Shared Libraries Linking in C

Tags: c, linker

```
  #include <stdio.h>

  int main()
  {
          printf("%s","Hello world");
          return 0;      
  }

  $gcc -o hello hello.c
```

Question:

1 - I believe the printf function's object file is statically linked. Is that correct?

2 - How should I configure/write this code so that the library files are dynamically linked or I mean it uses shared libraries at runtime?

Note: I am beginner in this concept, so feel free to correct me wherever it doesn't makes sense

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The linker takes whatever it finds. This is usually the shared library.

On a Linux system, you can use

```
file hello
```

to find out, whether it is linked statically or dynamically.

E.g.

```
file /bin/bash
```

gives

> /bin/bash: ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), **dynamically** linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.6.24, BuildID[sha1]=0x6dafe33f9353cbb054b1b1f7b079545992575757, stripped

whereas

```
file /bin/busybox
```

gives

> /bin/busybox: ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), **statically** linked, for GNU/Linux 2.6.24, BuildID[sha1]=0xac4943b7daf7c3c204a2866ea5398f2337ff93c9, stripped

You can force a static link, by adding the `-static` option to gcc

```
gcc -static -o hello hello.c

file hello
```

> /tmp/hello: ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1 (GNU/Linux), **statically** linked, for GNU/Linux 2.6.24, BuildID[sha1]=0x790ec9b287fd2a276162560e5e6669ba6b73e68f, not stripped

*Update:*

Linking is the process of putting object files, dynamic and static libraries and some boilerplate objects together, to form a binary executable file.

You can use both dynamic and static libraries in one executable. The needed object files of a static library are copied into the executable. On the other side, dynamic libraries (dynamic objects actually) are not copied, but rather referenced by the resulting binary.

*Update:*

There are two kinds of libraries, static libraries (ar archives, see [`man ar`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/ar.1.html))

```
file /usr/lib/libnet.a

/usr/lib/libnet.a: current ar archive
```

and dynamic libraries (dynamic objects)

```
file /usr/lib/libnet.so.1.5.0 

/usr/lib/libnet.so.1.5.0: ELF 64-bit LSB shared object, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, BuildID[sha1]=0x0c596357947e79001025b3c57be933690085dffb, stripped
```

You can have both types of library installed at the same time, e.g.

```
ls -l /usr/lib/libnet.*

-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 207780 Okt 28  2011 /usr/lib/libnet.a
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    802 Okt 28  2011 /usr/lib/libnet.la
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     15 Okt 28  2011 /usr/lib/libnet.so -> libnet.so.1.5.0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     15 Okt 28  2011 /usr/lib/libnet.so.1 -> libnet.so.1.5.0
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  92712 Okt 28  2011 /usr/lib/libnet.so.1.5.0
```

An `ar` archive contains one or more object files, which are selected by the linker if needed by the executable file. A shared object is an object with subroutines, which allows to be called by other shared objects or executables at runtime.

If you're interested in this subject, you can also look at this [Wikipedia - Library (computing)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Library_%28computing%29) article.

Comment: Doesn't linker do its job after compilation, i.e, it should be dynamic ? (Just for curiosity).

Comment: Yes, first the compiler creates the object file and in a second step, the linker creates the binary.

Comment: Then why the term **statically** link often comes into light?

Comment: I don't understand your question. What do you mean?

Comment: OK. First tell me that what does it mean by statically and dynamically linked ?

Comment: I would say, this is a question in itself, not a comment, isn't it? ;-) Anyway, see updated answer. I hope this makes it a bit clearer.

Comment: Yes. That's a question itself. I don't know about it :). And thanks to make it clear. +1.

Comment: @haccks "Doesn't linker do its job after compilation" - yes. "i.e, it should be dynamic" - no, why? there's no relation.

Comment: @H2CO3; Wohoooo! You got the right vein! :). I just thought about that and that's why asked it. By then I was not aware of static and dynamic libraries.

Comment: @Olaf so by default it used shared libraries, so how does it knows where to find those libraries?

Comment: @codeymodey Usually it does. It depends on how the compiler/linker is configured and what kind of libraries are installed. If you have static libraries only, it will link statically, of course.

Comment: According to my understanding library is the same whether it is static or shared.Only difference is one is part of executable and other is not. so i am unable to understand your statement, "what kind of libraries are installed"

Comment: Thank you..just to add to it, if the libraries are same so why do they need to exist in different forms(extensions), is the idea behind it to compress the static ones to save space..??

Comment: @codeymodey: there are significant differences between shared and static libraries: one is Position Independent Code, another is (on Windows) name prefixes, library initialization routines, and numerous other things that Olaf didn't mention to keep his answer from turning into an encyclopedia.